# How to link a folder with some .cpp and .h files in a another directory as a Include path to Unreal Engine Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, include-path, unreal-engine4

I have a UE4 project , And there is about 10 .cpp and .h files in another directory. I just want to add that directory as an Include path.

We can have script files in Source folder ,but let's say I have a folder with 10 .cpp and header files in D:\MyScripts and my unreal project is in D:\MyProj , I want to unreal to search for source files within that D:\Myscripts folder. when I compile the project, There should be a way to specify include paths.

Is this possible ? if possible how can i do ?

I searched internet nearly for two days, but I couldn't find anything helpful.
Hop someone can help me on this :)

Comment: Where is "another" directory? Did you mean it's not with "YourProject/Source/YourProject"?

Comment: Ok I've got it. I guess it's possible for adding additional include path, but I don't think that you can add additional sources files without putting those files into the same solution. Also if you wan't to use UE then I suggest that you should put your cpp and h files directly in to your project's /Source folder. Is there any reason that you don't want to put them in? Are they 3rd party codes?

Comment: Exactly , We have few third party codes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can create `make` file and add all the `.cpp` file and `.o` file.Reference link [here](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/).